# How to write keywords like 'Journal' in bib file

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to write a bibliography file.

Some of entries are not appearing in reference section. A blank line for that entry is appearing. I figured out that one of such entry have a keyword 'journal' in its 'Journal' field.

Please tell me how can I parse this special keyword.

```
    @article{Does voice matter?couper2004does,
  title={Does voice matter? An interactive voice response (IVR) experiment},
  author={Couper, Mick P and Singer, Eleanor and Tourangeau, Roger},
  journal={JOURNAL OF OFFICIAL STATISTICS-STOCKHOLM-},
  volume={20},
  number={3},
  pages={551--570},
  year={2004},
  publisher={ALMQVIST \& WIKSELL INTERNATIONAL}
}
```

These both journal and JOURNAL in 4th line are highlighted in same color. because of this only I am getting a blank entry in references section.

[image]

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}

\title{hello}
\author{rana}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{myfile}


\end{document}
```

Bibliography file myfile contains many entries like the one given above. But reference section in PDF generated after compilation, Starting few entries are empty as shown in snapshot.

please let me know in case more details are required.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your bibentry example is incomplete.

Comment: Just a } was missing. This entry along with others is not appearing in reference section.

Comment: Where is `acm_proc_article-sp.cls` from? On my full TL 2014 installation, there are only tex4t files for this

Comment: Downloaded it from ACM site. Don't remember the link exactly. Things were working fine before adding these new entries to bib file.

Comment: An enormous portion of journals have 'journal' in the title. There is certainly no **general** problem parsing fields which contain this value, and there is nothing special you have to do. Can you reproduce the issue with a standard class such as `article`? If not, that will suggest something in the class rather than your bib entries. If so, it would make it possible for people here to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to avoid problematic characters in your entry keys such as spaces and question marks. Then it works, at least with the standard `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}%acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{couper2004does,
  title={Does voice matter? An interactive voice response (IVR) experiment},
  author={Couper, Mick P and Singer, Eleanor and Tourangeau, Roger},
  journal={JOURNAL OF OFFICIAL STATISTICS-STOCKHOLM-},
  volume={20},
  number={3},
  pages={551--570},
  year={2004},
  publisher={ALMQVIST \& WIKSELL INTERNATIONAL}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\end{document}
```

[image: references]

Comment: Removing spaces worked. Although these spaces were not causing any issue in other entries. Anyways, its better not to  have space in key.

Comment: @User42 I can't explain why it would work. I would not expect it to. I get errors which clearly show that `bibtex` is parsing the key incorrectly. (It looks for entry with key `Does`, for example.) Anyway, glad it helped. The question mark seems OK but I'd remove it as well on the grounds that it is a special character and could cause issues. I recommend sticking to letters, numbers, hyphens and colons, for example. (Colons are popular but I've always used hyphens. However, I have nothing against colons as such.)